# How do I replace this pattern with a newline inside it?

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

If I have a text file with this content:

```
 someline
 <!--\
      file first read on 2015/01/11
```

And I want to delete `<!--\` and everything until what comes after "on", how do I do it? The expected output would be this with the example above:

```
someline
2015/01/11
```

I can't make a pattern that extracts dates, because `2015/01/11` can be just `Sunday` or `Yesterday` or almost anything else. `read` can also be anything. I tried this with BSD `sed`:

```
sed 's/<!--\
     file first .* on//g'
```

But when I run this command, I get this error:

```
sed: 1: "s/<!--\
        file f ...": unterminated substitute pattern
```

So I tried backslash escaping `<` and `!` but I got the same "unterminated substitute pattern" error. I tried to install GNU sed and do the same thing except `\n`, I also tried `gsed 's/<!--:a;N;$!ba;s/\n/file first .* on//g'` but I got:

```
gsed: -e expression #1, char 22: unknown option to `s'
```

Can `sed` not do this? If not, how do I do it with any other tool/language?

Comment: So your expected output is `someline \n file first read on`?

Comment: @pfnuesel No, it's `someline \n 2015/01/11` (with the example above)

Answer (score 2):

The following `sed` command should do what you want:

```
sed '/^<!--/{N; s/.*on *//}' inputfile
```

First we search for the regex `<!--` at the beginning of the line, than we use the `N` command to append the next line to it and delete (substitute with nothing, actually) everything till and with "on".

There are people claiming that whenever you use a capital letter command in `sed`, such as `N`, you are using the wrong tool...

Answer (score 2):

POSIXly:

```
$ sed -e '/<!--/{
  $!N
  s/.*on //
}' <in >out
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl can read the whole file with `-0777`, the `/s` modifier makes `.` match newlines, too:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/<!--\\.*?on //gs'
```

`*?` is a "frugal asterisk", which means "repeat zero or more times, but match the shortest string possible".